# Does GeoServer support FILTERs in GetFeature requests?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, ogc

I have a web client that filters WFS layers from various servers such as MapServer and GeoServer.

The following URL (encoding and removing whitespace does not make a difference):

```
https://ows-demo.terrestris.de/geoserver/osm/ows?version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typeNames=osm-fuel&count=10&exceptions=xml&filter=<fes:Filter xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/2.0/filterAll.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ogc:BBOX>    <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName><gml:Envelope xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3857"><gml:lowerCorner>-1400194.9520285155 6560917.375753866</gml:lowerCorner>      <gml:upperCorner>270219.8351193511 7459453.681587799</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope>  </ogc:BBOX></fes:Filter>
```

Returns an exception:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://ows-demo.terrestris.de/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="XML getFeature request SAX parsing error" locator="org.geoserver.ows.XmlRequestReader">
<ows:ExceptionText>org.xml.sax.SAXException: Attempted to construct illegal filter - I dont understand the tag: ogc:BBOX.  HINT: tags are case-sensitive!
Attempted to construct illegal filter - I dont understand the tag: ogc:BBOX.  HINT: tags are case-sensitive!</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

If I remove the outer `<filter></filter>` tags I get results:

```
https://ows-demo.terrestris.de/geoserver/osm/ows?version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typeNames=osm-fuel&count=10&exceptions=xml&filter=<ogc:BBOX>    <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName><gml:Envelope xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3857"><gml:lowerCorner>-1400194.9520285155 6560917.375753866</gml:lowerCorner>      <gml:upperCorner>270219.8351193511 7459453.681587799</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope></ogc:BBOX>
```

However these results don't appear to be spatially filtered - the same number of results are returned with or without the filter.

The `bbox` approach (suggested in the [GeoServer docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html#getfeature) works fine. The following returns the expected results:

https://ows-demo.terrestris.de/geoserver/osm/ows?version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typeNames=osm-fuel&count=10&exceptions=xml&bbox=-1400194.9520285155,6560917.375753866,270219.8351193511,7459453.681587799

However I was hoping for an approach that works with both MapServer and GeoServer. Note this approach was working (in 2020) so I'm wondering if something has changed, or a config setting has changed in a more recent version of GeoServer.

With some basic testing it seems as though MapServer does also support the `bbox` option so it could be possible to switch to this for all servers.

---

The following request brings back the expected results:

```
https://ows-demo.terrestris.de/geoserver/osm/ows?version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typeNames=osm-fuel&count=10&exceptions=xml&filter=<fes:Filter xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"><fes:BBOX><fes:ValueReference>the_geom</fes:ValueReference><gml:Envelope xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" srsName="EPSG:3857"><gml:lowerCorner>-1400194.9520285155 6560917.375753866</gml:lowerCorner><gml:upperCorner>270219.8351193511 7459453.681587799</gml:upperCorner></gml:Envelope></fes:BBOX></fes:Filter>
```

Note:

- BBOX is in the `fes` namespace (see [@IanTurton’s answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/467496/115))
- `<fes:ValueReference>the_geom</fes:ValueReference>` instead of `<ogc:PropertyName>`
- namespaces have to be included - without them there is no error but there is no spatial filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BBOX` lives in the `fes` namespace not the `ogc` one if you are using a WFS 2.0.0 server, I have a feeling it might work if you define an `ogc` namespace rather than an `fes` one. However, I suspect you need the `ogc` one for the `PropertyName` - sadly the examples in the spec don't have any namespaces (which is why I try not to use FES).